# Operating system not found after restart

Tags: bios

So I recently stumbled upon an old hard drive and I have used pretty much every operating system other than Linux so I installed Ubuntu but after installing it prompted to restart (I had installed it via a USB stick) so I did and then I got an error message popped up and said operating system not found and I don't know if my BIOS is screwing it up or if it was because the hard drive was an old Window's hard drive but it still was formatted so I don't see the problem

Comment: By the way I'm currently using a Lenovo IdeaCenter computer and I just wanted to setup the hard drive with Ubuntu and not keep it on this desktop but move it to my media computer so it may have to do with this computer

Comment: I have found some cheap devices fussy at getting Ubuntu to install on. Your lenovo may contain the same bios/uefi where the settings in BIOS/UEFI prevent any newer OS to install unless settings are a specific way. (secure boot options matching options elsewhere in bios). Installation will need to be on the end-computer though (*in my experience*) and not a moved hdd/ssd unless the uefi/bios setup allows for it (*or written to match what it required which is more work*); as it's a UEFI message from BIOS.